# Input is offset when changing text size next to it

Tags: html, css, navigation, inline, offset

Not sure why but whenever I change the links next to my search bar on my nav menu, For some reason the input gets slightly moved down. I'm not sure how to explain it....

```css
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@500&display=swap');
  body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.top-nav-bar {
  background-color: #292929;
  height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #DDDDEB;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.spacer {
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline;
  cursor: help;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
a:hover {
  color: #597BEB;
}
.searchbar {
  font-size: 16px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #CCCCCC;
  background-color: inherit;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav-bar">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <a href="#">Profile</a>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <input class="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="Search">
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `vertical-align:top;`?

```css
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@500&display=swap');
  body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.top-nav-bar {
  background-color: #292929;
  height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #DDDDEB;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.spacer {
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline;
  cursor: help;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
a:hover {
  color: #597BEB;
}
.searchbar {
  font-size: 16px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #CCCCCC;
  background-color: inherit;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-nav-bar">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <a href="#">Profile</a>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <input class="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="Search">
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```